# Is Facebook blocking my IP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Since morning today, I have started receiving the error below when trying to connect to FB through my ROR application.

There have not been any changes to code. Is it possible that Facebook is blocking my IP?

Please note, I receive this on the Production Server only and not on the development machine.

```
Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed (Network is unreachable - connect(2)):
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
  /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
```

Below is what I was able to conclude after a lot of help from @МалъСкрылевъ

```
deploy@www:~$ telnet graph.facebook.com 443 
Trying 31.13.71.144... 
Trying 2a03:2880:f003:b01:face:b00c:0:1... 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable 
deploy@www:~$ telnet graph.facebook.com 443 
Trying 31.13.69.80... 
Connected to star.c10r.facebook.com. 
Escape character is '^]'.
```

It did not connect in the first attempt...
..in the second attempt it connected. So it appears that certain IPs let it connect and certain IPs do not.

Is that possible?

Comment: unlikely. your oauth key may have been expired, but this will lead to another kind of error

Comment: What should be the next best step to try and fix/approach this issue?

Comment: try to ping FB from the server, then open empty `telnet facebook.com 80` http connection from the server.

Comment: Nope...

--- 80 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7056ms

Comment: so, your need make sure that the address/port, to which faraday is accessing, is available. so do it with telnet

Comment: I am able to telnet facebook.com 80

Comment: so could you find out the host/port to which faraday is tried to connect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66060/discussion-between-sb-and--).

Comment: Below is what I was able to conclude after a lot of help from @МалъСкрылевъ 

deploy@www:~$ telnet graph.facebook.com 443 
Trying 31.13.71.144... 
Trying 2a03:2880:f003:b01:face:b00c:0:1... 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable 
deploy@www:~$ telnet graph.facebook.com 443 
Trying 31.13.69.80... 
Connected to star.c10r.facebook.com. 
Escape character is '^]'.
It did not connect in the first attempt...
..in the second attempt it connected

Comment: try: `ping 31.13.71.144` and then `telnet 31.13.71.144 443`